# Close graph of multivalued function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Assume that $X,Y$ are two closed sets in $R^n$ (with the induced euclidian topology) and let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a multivalued function.
Assume also that the graph of $f$ is a closed subset in $X \times Y$
is the following true?

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n= x_0$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_*(x_n)$ (where $f_*(x_n)\in f(x_n)$) exists and converges for some $y\in f(x_0)$?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "converges for some $y \in f(x_0)$"? What is $y$ (in relation with $\lim_n f(x_n)$), and what does $y \in f(x_0)$ mean?

Comment: Since $f$ is a multivalued function then $f(x_0)$ is a set which can contain more then one value.

Comment: I see. I thought that by "multivalued function" you meant "multivariable function". But then, what does it mean $\lim_n f(x_n)$? There is no notion of convergence for multivalued functions.

Comment: The question come from the fact that if $f$ is a regular function (not multivalued) then the answer is true since the closeness of the graph is equivalent to the continuity of $f$.
I  edited my question

Comment: Anyway, this is not even true for classic single-valued functions. For example, the map $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = 1/x$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$, has closed graph but it is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Let $X=Y=[0,1]$ and let $$f(x)=\begin{cases} [0,1] \mbox{ for } x=0\\ \left\{ \sin x^{-1} \right\} \mbox{ for } 0<x\leq 1\end{cases}$$ then consider a sequence $x_{n}=\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi\right)^{-1} .$